# How to make simultaneous requests with mechanize?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, mechanize, mechanize-python

Is it possible to run more than one request with mechanize at a time? I know about threads, but the problem with threads is, that mechanize processes thread after thread and not all threads at the same time...

Here is what I want to do:
I want to fill a form on a page, submit it, get the resulting page, go back (br.back()) to the form on the last page, fill it with different details, submit it, get the resulting page and so on and so on...as this solution takes a long time, I was thinking of doing more requests at the same time, is there a way? Really looking forward to your answers.
Thank you very much!